# SQL query error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'."

Tags: sql-server

What's wrong with my code?

I want to pass BIT to retrieve inactive or active rows from TBL table.

This is the error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'.

Here's the code

```
CREATE function [CM].[fnSearch]
(
@Status bit
)
RETURNS Table
as 
RETURN
(
    SELECT *
    FrOM TBL
    WHERE  CASE @Status 
                WHEN '0' THEN (DeletedBy IS NULL) 
                ELSE (DeletedBy IS NOT NULL)
           END
)
```

**UPDATE:**

The ( before SELECT is my typing error.
Sorry about it.

Comment: I see a bracket before the select that is never closed.

Answer (score 6):

If I'm reading this right, you're trying to use `(DeletedBy IS [NOT] NULL)` as a boolean expression that evaluates to a bit value (either 1 or 0)? If so, you can't do that. You need something like this instead:

```
CASE WHEN (@Status = 0 AND DeletedBy IS NULL) OR DeletedBy IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL does not evaluate boolean expressions into `1` or `0`. You would have to set it to explicitly set it to 1 when `true`, and 0 when `false`.